# SQLite and Windows Phone 7.1

Tags: vb.net, sqlite, windows-phone-7

Depending on what i know, SQLite is supported in WP7.1, but i cant even import System.Data.SQLite to the project!!

should i download it as a dll specially for windows phone or am i missing something?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get the Windows Phone specific build of SQLite: http://sqlitewindowsphone.codeplex.com/

Comment: a perfect walkthrough i found:

 http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/silverlight/Windows-Phone-7-Native-Database-Programming-via-Sqlite-Client-for-Windows-Phone.aspx